# Zend form/save related

Tags: forms, zend-framework

I have been doing a form in zend which uses two forms to input data from user to the database the two forms are suppose to share the same id from the same table in the database, each time u fill the form where by the first form has a save and continue link at the bottom and the second form has a finished link. bt when processing the second form im currently receiving this error  Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::save() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Gforms2\application\models\DbTable\Kopano.php on line 43

here my code below

Thanks in advance

```
model db-table kopano

    public function firstkopanokopano($name, $surname, $nickname, $lastname)
    {
        $data = array(
            'name'=> $name,
            'surname'=> $surname,
            'nickname'=> $nickname,
            'lastname'=> $lastname,

        );
         return $this->insert($data);


    }

        public function secondkopanokopano($id, $age, $city, $province, $township)
    {
        $row = $this->find($id)->current;

        $row->age = $age;
        $row->city = $city;
        $row->province = $province;
        $row->township = $township;



        $row->save();//where error is calling from
        //$this->insert($data);
    }

IndexController

    public function firstkopanoAction()
      {
         $form = new Application_Form_Firstkopano();


        $this->view->form = $form;

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            if ($form->isValid($formData)) {                

                $name = $form->getValue('name');
                $surname = $form->getValue('surname');
                $nickname = $form->getValue('nickname');
                $lastname = $form->getValue('lastname');

                $kopano = new Application_Model_DbTable_Kopano();
                $id = $kopano->firstkopanoKopano($name, $surname, $nickname, $lastname);

                //$id = $this->insert($id);

                $this->_redirect('index/Secondkopano/id/'.$id);
            } else {
                $form->populate($formData);
            }
        }
    }
    public function secondkopanoAction()
    {
         $id = $this->_request->getparam('id');
         $form = new Application_Form_Secondkopano();


        $this->view->form = $form;

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            if ($form->isValid($formData)) {                

                $age = $form->getValue('age');
                $city = $form->getValue('city');
                $province = $form->getValue('province');
                $township = $form->getValue('township');

                $kopano= new Application_Model_DbTable_Kopano();
                $kopano->secondkopanoKopano($id, $age, $city, $province, $township);



                $this->_helper->redirect('index');
            } else {
                $form->populate($formData);
            }
        }
    }


forms 1st

<?php

class Application_Form_Firstkopano extends Zend_Form
{

    public function init()
    {

        $name = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('name');
        $name->setLabel('Name')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('NotEmpty');

        $surname = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('surname');
        $surname->setLabel('Surname')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('NotEmpty');

        $nickname = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('nickname');
        $nickname->setLabel('Nickname')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('NotEmpty');

        $lastname = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('lastname');
        $lastname->setLabel('Lastname')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('NotEmpty');


        $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
        $submit->setLabel('Next');
        $submit->setAttrib('id', 'submitbutton');

        $this->addElements(array($id, $name, $surname, $nickname, $lastname, $submit));

    }


}


2nd

<?php

class Application_Form_Secondkopano extends Zend_Form
{

    public function init()
    {
        $age= new Zend_Form_Element_Text('age');
        $age->setLabel('Age')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('Digits');

        $city = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('city');
        $city->setLabel('City')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('NotEmpty');

        $province = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('province');
        $province->setLabel('Province')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('NotEmpty');

        $township = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('township');
        $township->setLabel('Township')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('NotEmpty');


        $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
        $submit->setLabel('Next');
        $submit->setAttrib('id', 'submitbutton');

        $this->addElements(array($id, $age, $city, $province, $township, $submit));

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the function to:

```
  public function secondkopanokopano($id, $age, $city, $province, $township)
        {
            $row = $this->find($id)->current();

            $row->age = $age;
            $row->city = $city;
            $row->province = $province;
            $row->township = $township;

            return $row->save();
        }
```